# Infinite rationals approaching irrational within denominator squared

Tags: number-theory, continued-fractions

We have been asked to prove that given an irrational $\alpha$ there exist infinitely many relatively prime pairs $(p,q)$ such that $|p/q-\alpha|<1/q^2$. I have so far found a constructive solution with continued fractions, but only existence is required and I feel like there must be a much more concise and precise solution that does not require introducing continued fractions. As a tip we are told to use the pigeonhole principle.

Any other tips or piece of advice will be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dirichlet approximation theorem proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2557926/dirichlet-approximation-theorem-proof). (Your question is an easy corollary of Dirichlet's theorem)

Comment: This question may help you.https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/380378/pigeonhole-proof-of-rational-approximation-theorem